# "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" when I try to parse JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I get the following JSON by the requests library:

```
 {       
     "tracks":[
   {
     "bframes":0,
     "bitrate":155,
     "codec":"h264",
     "content":"video",
     "fps":25.0,
     "gop_size":25,
     "height":240,
     "last_gop":25,
     "level":"2.1",
     "pix_fmt":"yuv420p",
     "pixel_height":240,
     "pixel_width":320,
     "profile":"Baseline",
     "sar_height":1,
     "sar_width":1,
     "track_id":"v1",
     "width":320
  },
  {
     "bitrate":28,
     "channels":2,
     "codec":"aac",
     "content":"audio",
     "lang":"eng",
     "sample_rate":48000,
     "track_id":"a1"
  }   
 ] 
}
```

I need to get a key and value of gop, fps and lang.

I tried to do it in the following way:

```
    media_info = requests.get(url)        
    media_data = media_info.json()
    media_info_data = media_data[0]['tracks'][0]['fps']
```

But I got the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What should I do in this situation?

Comment: Try decomposing. `media_data[0]` followed by `media_data[0]['tracks']` etc... til fps. Post the traceback which will show you which one is wrong.

Comment: You should use `json.loads` first and it turn into a `dict`

Answer (score 1):

Your `media_data` is not a list but a dictionary; try

```
media_info_data = media_data['tracks'][0]['fps']
```